# Building a 77GHz Band FMCW Radar with 0.25 Degree Angular Resolution

Tags: radar

First some context. My group recently acquired some hardware for a radar related project, specifically a Texas Instrument AWR1843Boost (https://www.ti.com/tool/AWR1843BOOST) and a Texas Instruments DCA1000 EVM Capture Card (https://www.ti.com/tool/DCA1000EVM). Unfortunately, the AWR1843 does not have the angular resolution required for our application (we need about 0.25 degrees in the 77GHz band). Our original plan was to connect 2 AWR1843 modules together separated by some distance (basically a cascade system) and so increase the angular resolution. When asked, TI told us the AWR1843 doesn't support this functionality since multiple boards cannot be synchronized, and we should instead use a TIDEP-01012 (https://www.ti.com/tool/TIDEP-01012). The issue is that the TIDEP-01012 is significantly more expensive and still wouldn't offer the resolution we need, also given the extensive configurability of the AWR1843 it seems odd that it has no support for external triggering or synchronisation.

**What radar system can we use that has an angular resolution of 0.25 degrees in the mm-wave band?**

The more prebuilt the system the better, but pointers to suppliers or resources that could be used to build our own system would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you asking for a product recommendation? Because that would be off-topic.

Comment: 0.25 degrees resolution is going to require an antenna over a meter wide at those frequencies.  Doing that with a phased array is not simple, and probably not very useful with so few elements in the array.  Have you considered using a fixed ~1.2m diameter dish?  You could manually point the dish, or even put a smaller phased array at the focus.

Comment: In a cascade system the angular resolution is a function of the number of virtual antennas and field of view. What is your targeted field of view?

Comment: Thanks for the prompt responses, and please excuse my ignorance, I am still very new to FMCW radars. The AWR1843 has 12 virtual antennas set at lambda/2 for a 90 degree FoV. At most, we need about 50 deg. We don't have space requirements, so a dish could work. Would it be as simple as placing the AWR1843 at the focus of something like a satellite TV receiver dish? I assume the dish would need to be specifically designed for the wavelength and FoV?